# How to use Serbian cyrillic script with Polyglossia and minted

Tags: minted, polyglossia, cyrillic, pdfsync

I'm using `polyglossia` for writing a document in Serbian cyrillic script, but when I try to use `minted` for source code syntax highlighting there's an error (although pdf is generated):

```
polyglossia: The current roman font does not contain the Cyrill(polyglossia) Please define \cyrillicfont with \newfontfamily. ...l=lst:rssfeeder,caption=RssItemView.java]
```

Pdf is generated, but without cyrillic words in `minted` environment. Note that there is no error if I don't use `minted`.

I defined `cyrillicfont` in premble:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,serbian,oneside]{book}

% minted  - paket za prikaz programa
\usepackage{minted}

% srpski jezik
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[Script=Cyrillic]{serbian}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfont{Times New Roman}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage{pdfsync}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}


% Numerisanje subsubcetion
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

%Prikaz subsubsection u sadrzaju
%\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

% Komanda za horizontal ruler
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}
```

I'm trying to show this `coffeescript` snippet with `minted`:

```
\begin{minted}[mathescape,
               linenos]{coffeescript}
  http = require 'http'

  app.get '/', (req, res) =>
    res.send 'cao'
  # Коментар / Comment : const double pi = 3.1415926535
\end{minted}
```

Pdf is generated, the code is shown, but instead of Коментар there are blanks. Following errors and warnings are displayed:

```
polyglossia: The current roman font does not contain the Cyrill(polyglossia) Please define \cyrillicfont with \newfontfamily. ...\catcode`\$=3\catcode`\^=7\catcode`\_=8}, ]
Unused global option(s): [serbian].
Font shape `EU1/TimesNewRoman(0)/m/sc' undefined(Font) using `EU1/TimesNewRoman(0)/m/n' instead
Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.
```

I'm using `TexStudio` and `xelatex` with `--shell-escape` option for `minted`.

1. Why is the error with defining cyrillic font displayed when I included it in the preamble?
2. How to show cyrillic words in `minted` environment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to define a monospaced font that supports Cyrillic; the default one (Latin Modern Mono) doesn't.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,serbian,oneside]{book}

% minted  - paket za prikaz programa
\usepackage{minted}

% srpski jezik
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[Script=Cyrillic]{serbian}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\cyrillicfont{Times New Roman}
\setmonofont{CMU Typewriter Text}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}


% Numerisanje subsubcetion
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

%Prikaz subsubsection u sadrzaju
%\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

% Komanda za horizontal ruler
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}

\begin{document}
I'm trying to show this coffeescript snippet with minted:

\begin{minted}[mathescape,
               linenos]{coffeescript}
  http = require 'http'

  app.get '/', (req, res) =>
    res.send 'cao'
  # Коментар / Comment : const double pi = 3.1415926535
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

Find a monospaced font you have available. If CMU Typewriter Text is not installed as system font, you should do with

```
\setmonofont{cmuntt.otf}
```

provided you have a full TeX distribution.

Don't load `ucs` with XeLaTeX; also `pdfsync` should be avoided: its synchronization capabilities are much worse than the modern SyncTeX mechanism which is provided automatically by the more recent TeX distributions (add the option `-pdfsync=1`, which most front-ends already do).

[image]